# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar los números negativos?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando filtrar números negativos en java, y solamente he podido filtrar los caracteres. Ademas de esto, quiero que vuelva a preguntar de nuevo, es decir que no pare la condición. Lo he hecho con hasNext y luego los he sacado del buffer. De momento tengo hecho esto:

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int F; 
        int C; 

        System.out.println("Introduce el número 1");
        boolean esUnNumeroValidoF = scanner.hasNextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduce el número 2");
        boolean esUnNumeroValidoC = scanner.hasNextInt();

        if (esUnNumeroValidoF) {
            int numeroIntroducidoF = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            if (esUnNumeroValidoC) {
                int numeroIntroducidoC = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();

               } else {

                System.out.println("Error, no has introducido un número entero. Prueba de nuevo");
                scanner.nextLine();
               }

            } else {

            System.out.println("Error, no has introducido un número entero. Prueba de nuevo");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres que se repita cuando introduzcan un número negativo puedes hacer un bucle `do-while` almacenando el número para saber si es válido. Algo parecido a esto:

```
boolean esUnNumeroValidoF = false;

do{
    System.out.println("Introduce el número 1");
    int numero = scanner.nextInt();

    if (numero < 0){
       esunNumeroValidoF = false;
    }else{
        esunNumeroValidoF = true;
    }
}while(!esUnNumeroValidoF);
```

Esto lo tendrías que realizar cada vez que quieres comprobar que el número que introducen es correcto o crear una función pasandole como parámetro el número para no tener que copiar código (esta última opción la más rentable y la que te recomiendo).

Como aclaración, tal y como ha comentado `@Dev.Joel` se podría haber usado directamente la condición en el bucle, sin variables booleanas. Simplemente lo hice así para que el OP lo pudiera comparar con su código. Sin embargo, el código simplificado y dentro de una función quedaría como:

```
public static int dameUnPositivo(int indice){
    int numero;

    do{
         System.out.println("Introduce el número " + indice);
         numero = scanner.nextInt();
    }while(numero < 0);

    return numero;
}
```

donde índice sería el orden a la hora de introducir los números (número 1, número 2, número 3, etc).

Mediante esta función, tu llamarías a esta función y ella te devolvería un número entero, ya que ya habría hecho la validación de si es negativo o positivo dentro de la misma.

Para llamarla, simplemente tendrías que hacer lo siguiente desde tu método principal, y dando por hecho que `numero1` y `numero2` es donde quieres almacenar los dos primeros números:

```
int numero1 = dameUnPositivo(1);
int numero2 = dameUnPositivo(2);
```

Como ves, con una función te puedes ahorrar muchas líneas de código que son prácticamente iguales.

Por supuesto, hay mil formas de hacer el mismo camino pero creo que esta es la más simple de todas. En caso de que quisieras devolver un booleano simplemente tendrías que utilizar esta función con el `if` del primer fragmento de código y devolver `esunNumeroValidoF`.

Comment: Es una respuesta válida. Pero creo que no hace falta una variable booleana. Directamente la condición  del if pudo haber ido en el while.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Sí, tal y como dices se podría haber hecho directamente (y mejor) pero lo he hecho así para que pueda comparar con su código y ver la diferencia.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes preguntarle también cuantos números quiere filtrar y hacer un `For` o `Do While` he usado el código de **@Error404** ya que estaba bien planteado, pero tan solo cambiando el Do While por el for

```
int contador = 0;
boolean esUnNumeroValidoF = false;
System.out.println("¿Cúantos números quieres comprobar?");
contador = scanner.nextInt();

for(int i = 0; i < contador; i++){
 System.out.println("Introduce el número 1");
  int numero = scanner.nextInt();

  esunNumeroValidoF = numero < 0;

}
```

Comment: Gracias, algunas teclas del teclado son demasiado duras jaja

Comment: Gracias por nombrarme. Sin embargo veo un fallo en tu código. El do-while lo va a realizar (en el caso de mi respuesta) hasta que encuentre un número válido y en ese momento se saldrá del bucle. En tu caso compruebas si el número es válido pero si has puesto que se compruebe tres veces, si en la segunda iteración el número que introduce es válido, va a seguir haciendo una tercera comprobación. Tendrías que hacer una doble condición en tu for para que se salga del bucle cuando encuentre un valor válido. `for(int i = 0; ((i < contador) && (esunNumeroValidoF == false)); i++)`

Comment: @Error404 lo he hecho así porque el OP ha puesto esto en su pregunta: _Ademas de esto, quiero que vuelva a preguntar de nuevo, es decir que no pare la condición._ A lo mejor no se ha explicado bien, o no nos aclaramos con la pregunta, pero vamos, respuestas tiene unas cuantas ya para comparar

Comment: Sí, yo también he leído eso pero entiendo que es que no pare la condición hasta que un nuevo número esté correcto. No le veo sentido a que una comprobación, al tener ya un valor correcto, siga pidiendo nuevos valores.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar!!! Perdonar si no me he explicado bien, pero me refiero a antes de nada, comprobar si es un numero negativo, y si es negativo que vuelva a pedir hasta que se introduzca un numero entero positivo. De todas maneras, voy a probar a lo que me habéis escrito, de nuevo muchas gracias ;)

Comment: Entonces.... Para aclararme. ¿Tu quieres que vayan metiendo números, hasta que uno de estos sea positivo? Ej: "negativo", vuelve a pedir, "negativo", vuelve a pedir, etc.... "positivo". Fin del programa Si te refieres a eso dímelo y actualizo mi respuesta

Comment: Hola @bpico, mira a ver si te es de ayuda mi respuesta. En mi respuesta, introduces un número y si es negativo, vuelve a realizar el bucle. Así hasta que encuentre un número positivo y entonces se sale del bucle. De esta manera, entrará siempre mínimo una vez al bucle (por eso he usado un bucle `do-while` en vez de `while`) y no tendrás que repetir la línea en la que coges el número fuera del bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Con un while y la variable bool error se soluciona rápido:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int error = 0;

while (error < 1)
{
    System.out.println("Introduce el número 1");
    boolean esUnNumeroValidoF = scanner.hasNextInt();

    System.out.println("Introduce el número 2");
    boolean esUnNumeroValidoC = scanner.hasNextInt();

    if (esUnNumeroValidoF) 
    {
        int numeroIntroducidoF = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        if (esUnNumeroValidoC) 
        {
            int numeroIntroducidoC = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            error = 1;//saldría del bucle, porque los dos números son correctos

        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error, no has introducido un número natural. Prueba de nuevo\n");
        }

    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Error, no has introducido un número natural. Prueba de nuevo");
        scanner.nextLine();
    }

}


scanner.close();
```

Como apunte, te valdrían números naturales. Es decir, los negativos son números enteros, tú lo que buscas es que metan números naturales.

Comment: Tienes razón, ahora lo pruebo ;)

Comment: @bpico ¿qué tal te funcionó?

Comment: He hecho lo que me dijiste, pero el "boolean error" no finaliza en el if cuando es declarado como false :(

Comment: A lo mejor por poner `while (error)` en lugar de `while (error == true)`. Te lo he puesto con un int y he quitado F y C que sobraban. Mira qué tal así :)

Comment: Hola cluna. ¿Has probado el código com tus últimas modificaciones? Por que no creo que compile en Java.

Comment: Hola, @sstan, la verdad es que no he podido probarlo. Pero cambio la condición del while, gracias :)